# Count duplicate records by using linq

Tags: sql, linq

Count duplicate records by using linq
.................................................................................................................................................

```
Col1  col2
x       a
x       a
x       b
x       b
y       c
y       c
y       d
y       d
z       e
z       e
z       f
```

now i want count like follows

```
x  a 2
x  b 2
y  c 2
y  d 2
```

in linq plese any one assist me

Comment: Hello, please consider checking [ask]

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: var duplicates = (from c in Table
                 group c by new { c.col1, c.col2} into g
                 where g.Count() > 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table
.GroupBy(x=>new{x.col1,x.clo2})
.Select(x=>new{ x.key.col1,x.key.col2,x.Count(z=>z.col1)
```

Comment: `x.Count()` at the end would do the job too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result =
from t in table
group t by new
{
    t.col1,
    t.col2,
} into gt
select new
{
    col1 = gt.Key.col1,
    col2 = gt.Key.col2,
    count = gt.Count(),
};
```